# KeyError: color='variable' using plot

Tags: python, plot

I am trying to run the following script. I am getting a KeyError on the function trying to plot stock returns.

It seems to be coming from fig = px.line(grouped_metrics, x="Date Snapshot", y="value", **color='variable'**). However, it is a valid column in my df. I have tried adding different columns in the color= argument but I get the same error. My three columns are 'variable', 'value', 'Date Snapshot'. Appologies for the block of code:

[Data for ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/662Ti.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import plotly.express as px
import yfinance as yf
import pandas_market_calendars as mcal
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, plot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)


def create_market_cal(start, end):
    nyse = mcal.get_calendar('NYSE')
    schedule = nyse.schedule(stocks_start, stocks_end)
    market_cal = mcal.date_range(schedule, frequency='1D')
    market_cal = market_cal.tz_localize(None)
    market_cal = [i.replace(hour=0) for i in market_cal]
    return market_cal


def get_data(stocks, start, end):
    def data(ticker):
        df = yf.download(ticker, start=start, end=(end + datetime.timedelta(days=1)))
        df['symbol'] = ticker
        df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
        return df
    datas = map(data, stocks)
    return(pd.concat(datas, keys=stocks, names=['Ticker', 'Date'], sort=True))


def get_benchmark(benchmark, start, end):
    benchmark = get_data(benchmark, start, end)
    benchmark = benchmark.drop(['symbol'], axis=1)
    benchmark.reset_index(inplace=True)
    return benchmark

portfolio_df = pd.read_csv('C:\\tmp\\stock_transactions.csv')
portfolio_df['Open date'] = pd.to_datetime(portfolio_df['Open date'])
symbols = portfolio_df.Symbol.unique()
stocks_start = datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 1)
stocks_end = datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 10)
daily_adj_close = get_data(symbols, stocks_start, stocks_end)
daily_adj_close = daily_adj_close[['Close']].reset_index()
daily_benchmark = get_benchmark(['SPY'], stocks_start, stocks_end)
daily_benchmark = daily_benchmark[['Date', 'Close']]
market_cal = create_market_cal(stocks_start, stocks_end)

def position_adjust(daily_positions, sale):
    stocks_with_sales = pd.DataFrame()
    buys_before_start = daily_positions[daily_positions['Type'] == 'Buy'].sort_values(by='Open date')
    for position in buys_before_start[buys_before_start['Symbol'] == sale[1]['Symbol']].iterrows():
        if position[1]['Qty'] <= sale[1]['Qty']:
            sale[1]['Qty'] -= position[1]['Qty']
            position[1]['Qty'] = 0
        else:
            position[1]['Qty'] -= sale[1]['Qty']
            sale[1]['Qty'] -= sale[1]['Qty']
        stocks_with_sales = stocks_with_sales.append(position[1])
    return stocks_with_sales


def portfolio_start_balance(portfolio, start_date):
    positions_before_start = portfolio[portfolio['Open date'] <= start_date]
    future_sales = portfolio[(portfolio['Open date'] >= start_date) & (portfolio['Type'] == 'Sell')]
    sales = positions_before_start[positions_before_start['Type'] =='Sell'].groupby(['Symbol'])['Qty'].sum()
    sales = sales.reset_index()
    positions_no_change = positions_before_start[~positions_before_start['Symbol'].isin(sales['Symbol'].unique())]
    adj_positions_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for sale in sales.iterrows():
        adj_positions = position_adjust(positions_before_start, sale)
        adj_positions_df = adj_positions_df.append(adj_positions)
    adj_positions_df = adj_positions_df.append(positions_no_change)
    adj_positions_df = adj_positions_df.append(future_sales)
    adj_positions_df = adj_positions_df[adj_positions_df['Qty'] > 0]
    return adj_positions_df

active_portfolio = portfolio_start_balance(portfolio_df, stocks_start)

def fifo(daily_positions, sales, date):
    sales = sales[sales['Open date'] == date]
    daily_positions = daily_positions[daily_positions['Open date'] <= date]
    positions_no_change = daily_positions[~daily_positions['Symbol'].isin(sales['Symbol'].unique())]
    adj_positions = pd.DataFrame()
    for sale in sales.iterrows():
        adj_positions = adj_positions.append(position_adjust(daily_positions, sale))
    adj_positions = adj_positions.append(positions_no_change)
    adj_positions = adj_positions[adj_positions['Qty'] > 0]
    return adj_positions


def time_fill(portfolio, market_cal):
    sales = portfolio[portfolio['Type'] == 'Sell'].groupby(['Symbol','Open date'])['Qty'].sum()
    sales = sales.reset_index()
    per_day_balance = []
    for date in market_cal:
        if (sales['Open date'] == date).any():
            portfolio = fifo(portfolio, sales, date)
        daily_positions = portfolio[portfolio['Open date'] <= date]
        daily_positions = daily_positions[daily_positions['Type'] == 'Buy']
        daily_positions['Date Snapshot'] = date
        per_day_balance.append(daily_positions)
    return per_day_balance

positions_per_day = time_fill(active_portfolio, market_cal)


def modified_cost_per_share(portfolio, adj_close, start_date):
    df = pd.merge(portfolio, adj_close, left_on=['Date Snapshot', 'Symbol'],
                  right_on=['Date', 'Ticker'], how='left')
    df.rename(columns={'Close': 'Symbol Adj Close'}, inplace=True)
    df['Adj cost daily'] = df['Symbol Adj Close'] * df['Qty']
    df = df.drop(['Ticker', 'Date'], axis=1)
    return df


def benchmark_portfolio_calcs(portfolio, benchmark):
    portfolio = pd.merge(portfolio, benchmark, left_on=['Date Snapshot'],
                         right_on=['Date'], how='left')
    portfolio = portfolio.drop(['Date'], axis=1)
    portfolio.rename(columns={'Close': 'Benchmark Close'}, inplace=True)
    benchmark_max = benchmark[benchmark['Date'] == benchmark['Date'].max()]
    portfolio['Benchmark End Date Close'] = portfolio.apply(lambda x: benchmark_max['Close'], axis=1)
    benchmark_min = benchmark[benchmark['Date'] == benchmark['Date'].min()]
    portfolio['Benchmark Start Date Close'] = portfolio.apply(lambda x: benchmark_min['Close'], axis=1)
    return portfolio


def portfolio_end_of_year_stats(portfolio, adj_close_end):
    adj_close_end = adj_close_end[adj_close_end['Date'] == adj_close_end['Date'].max()]
    portfolio_end_data = pd.merge(portfolio, adj_close_end, left_on='Symbol',
                                  right_on='Ticker')
    portfolio_end_data.rename(columns={'Close': 'Ticker End Date Close'}, inplace=True)
    portfolio_end_data = portfolio_end_data.drop(['Ticker', 'Date'], axis=1)
    return portfolio_end_data


def portfolio_start_of_year_stats(portfolio, adj_close_start):
    adj_close_start = adj_close_start[adj_close_start['Date'] == adj_close_start['Date'].min()]
    portfolio_start = pd.merge(portfolio, adj_close_start[['Ticker', 'Close', 'Date']],
                                    left_on='Symbol', right_on='Ticker')
    portfolio_start.rename(columns={'Close': 'Ticker Start Date Close'}, inplace=True)
    portfolio_start['Adj cost per share'] = np.where(portfolio_start['Open date'] <= portfolio_start['Date'],
                                                          portfolio_start['Ticker Start Date Close'],
                                                          portfolio_start['Adj cost per share'])
    portfolio_start['Adj cost'] = portfolio_start['Adj cost per share'] * portfolio_start['Qty']
    portfolio_start = portfolio_start.drop(['Ticker', 'Date'], axis=1)
    portfolio_start['Equiv Benchmark Shares'] = portfolio_start['Adj cost'] / portfolio_start['Benchmark Start Date Close']
    portfolio_start['Benchmark Start Date Cost'] = portfolio_start['Equiv Benchmark Shares'] * portfolio_start['Benchmark Start Date Close']
    return portfolio_start


def calc_returns(portfolio):
    portfolio['Benchmark Return'] = portfolio['Benchmark Close'] / portfolio['Benchmark Start Date Close'] - 1
    portfolio['Ticker Return'] = portfolio['Symbol Adj Close'] / portfolio['Adj cost per share'] - 1
    portfolio['Ticker Share Value'] = portfolio['Qty'] * portfolio['Symbol Adj Close']
    portfolio['Benchmark Share Value'] = portfolio['Equiv Benchmark Shares'] * portfolio['Benchmark Close']
    portfolio['Abs Value Compare'] = portfolio['Ticker Share Value'] - portfolio['Benchmark Start Date Cost']
    portfolio['Abs Value Return'] = portfolio['Abs Value Compare']/portfolio['Benchmark Start Date Cost']
    portfolio['Stock Gain / (Loss)'] = portfolio['Ticker Share Value'] - portfolio['Adj cost']
    portfolio['Benchmark Gain / (Loss)'] = portfolio['Benchmark Share Value'] - portfolio['Adj cost']
    portfolio['Abs. Return Compare'] = portfolio['Ticker Return'] - portfolio['Benchmark Return']
    return portfolio


def per_day_portfolio_calcs(per_day_holdings, daily_benchmark, daily_adj_close, stocks_start):
    df = pd.concat(per_day_holdings, sort=True)
    mcps = modified_cost_per_share(df, daily_adj_close, stocks_start)
    bpc = benchmark_portfolio_calcs(mcps, daily_benchmark)
    pes = portfolio_end_of_year_stats(bpc, daily_adj_close)
    pss = portfolio_start_of_year_stats(pes, daily_adj_close)
    returns = calc_returns(pss)
    return returns

combined_df = per_day_portfolio_calcs(positions_per_day, daily_benchmark, daily_adj_close, stocks_start)


def line(df, val_1, val_2):
    grouped_metrics = combined_df.groupby(['Date Snapshot'])[[val_1, val_2]].sum().reset_index()
    grouped_metrics = pd.melt(grouped_metrics, id_vars=['Date Snapshot'],
                              value_vars=[val_1, val_2])
    fig = px.line(grouped_metrics, x="Date Snapshot", y="value",
                  color='variable')
    plot(fig)


line(combined_df, 'Stock Gain / (Loss)', 'Benchmark Gain / (Loss)')


def line_facets(df, val_1, val_2):
    grouped_metrics = combined_df.groupby(['Symbol', 'Date Snapshot'])[[val_1, val_2]].sum().reset_index()
    grouped_metrics = pd.melt(grouped_metrics, id_vars=['Symbol', 'Date Snapshot'],
                              value_vars=[val_1, val_2])
    fig = px.line(grouped_metrics, x="Date Snapshot", y="value",
                  color='variable', facet_col="Symbol", facet_col_wrap=5)
    plot(fig)


line_facets(combined_df, 'Ticker Return', 'Benchmark Return')
```

The above throws the following error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-337cc930bd36> in <module>
    183 
    184 
--> 185 line(combined_df, 'Stock Gain / (Loss)', 'Benchmark Gain / (Loss)')
    186 
    187 

<ipython-input-4-337cc930bd36> in line(df, val_1, val_2)
    179                               value_vars=[val_1, val_2])
    180     fig = px.line(grouped_metrics, x="Date Snapshot", y="value",
--> 181                   color='variable')
    182     plot(fig)
    183 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\express\_chart_types.py in line(data_frame, x, y, line_group, color, line_dash, hover_name, hover_data, custom_data, text, facet_row, facet_col, facet_col_wrap, facet_row_spacing, facet_col_spacing, error_x, error_x_minus, error_y, error_y_minus, animation_frame, animation_group, category_orders, labels, orientation, color_discrete_sequence, color_discrete_map, line_dash_sequence, line_dash_map, log_x, log_y, range_x, range_y, line_shape, render_mode, title, template, width, height)
    250     a polyline mark in 2D space.
    251     """
--> 252     return make_figure(args=locals(), constructor=go.Scatter)
    253 
    254 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\express\_core.py in make_figure(args, constructor, trace_patch, layout_patch)
   1887                 prefix = get_label(args, args["facet_row"]) + "="
   1888                 row_labels = [prefix + str(s) for s in sorted_group_values[m.grouper]]
-> 1889             for val in sorted_group_values[m.grouper]:
   1890                 if val not in m.val_map:
   1891                     m.val_map[val] = m.sequence[len(m.val_map) % len(m.sequence)]

KeyError: 'variable'
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone comes across this issue: I had the same situation, in my case the error message was misleading: root cause was that the dataframe in px.line() was emtpy (no rows).